# interpretation of "tangent space" in function space

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

$H$ is the Hilbert space of mean-zero square-integrable $p$-dimensional functions on the unit interval. Let $f$ be a mean-zero square-integrable $q$-dimensional function on the unit interval.  One text describes the linear subspace "generated" by $f$ as
$$
\{Bf : B\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times q}\}.
$$
It goes on to describe this subspace as a "tangent space." How does this space relate to a tangent space as taught in elementary courses, e.g., a plane touching a sphere? I am trying to understand why the term "tangent" is being used here.

Comment: @g.s So your $Z$ corresponds to my $H$, I believe? and your $H$ is some ambient function space?

Comment: Sorry I misread:  Without looking at the textbook you're reading and thus the context in which this scenario is presented, as a Hilbert (linear) space, $H$ is an infinite-dimensional smooth manifold. Then your linear subspace $\{Bf:B\in\mathbb{R}^{p\times q}\}$ is the tangent space to $H$ at $f$. So you may want to look at the definition of a tangent space of an infinite-dimensional manifold, in say springer.com/gp/book/9780387985930 or springer.com/gp/book/9780387967905.